# How can align all photos on one side of the with text in a list form next to them webpage

Tags: html, css, web

Somewhat like a ebay search page like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFImR.png)

in my code, only the first listed item looks just like the image above, but every picture after floats to the right side of the page, but the text stays on left.
I want it to look like this:

[]-list

[] -list

[] -list

with the code I have, the image in the second div is pushed to the right side. I want all images and text aligned underneath each other to look somewhat like the ebay layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>

<html>

<style>

*, html {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
color: #000;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: Arial;
}

.clear {
clear: both
}

product_img 
{
display:flex;
40px 
}


.businessInfo 
{
float: left;
margin-left: 12px;
width: 552px;
text-align: left;
}
.businessName 
{
float: left;
margin-top: 2px;
text-align: left;
color: #ffffff ;
}

.sitePromotion 
{
float: left;
margin-top: 6px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #ffffff ;
}
.baseLocation{
float: left;
font-size: 15px;
background: #ffffff ;
}
.location {
float: left;
font-size: 15px;
color: #ffffff ;
}
.contactInfo {
float: left;
margin-top: 4px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #ffffff ;
}

.connectInfo {
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #ffffff ;
}
.moreConnectInfo {
float: left;
margin-top: 6px;
font-size: 15px;
color: #ffffff;
}





</style>
</head>
<body>
<body style="background-color:black;">


<h1 style= "color:grey;font-size:50px;">dollas</h1>
<h2 style="color:white; font-size:25px;;">North Jersey</h2>
<hr>


<!-- business 2-->
<div class="product_img">
<img alt="KB's BBQ SMOKEHOUSE - IRVINGTON, NJ 07111 (Menu &amp; Order 
Online)" class="n3VNCb" 
src="https://menufyproduction.imgix.net/637255010998628698+201756.png? 
auto=compress,format&amp;h=1080&amp;w=1920&amp;fit=max" data-noaft="1" 
jsname="HiaYvf" jsaction="load:XAeZkd;" style="width: 200px; height: 
150px; margin: 0px;">
</div> 
</div>
<div class="businessInfo"> 
<div class="businessName"><a href="">KB's BBQ Smokehouse</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="location">Location: 1077 Stuyvesant Ave, Irvington, NJ 
07111</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="contactInfo">Phone: (973) 982-6528</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="connectInfo">Website:https://kbbbqsmokehouse.com/ </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<!-- business 3-->

<div class="product_img">
<img data-visualcompletion="media-vc-image" alt="May be an image of 1 person 
and text that says 'Ard Bakery Arielitas'" class="ji94ytn4 r9f5tntg d2edcug0 
r0294ipz" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin" 
src="https://scontent.fewr1- 
5.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.18172- 
8/26198629_1997772167107826_8453467514730795477_o.jpg?_nc_cat=105&amp;ccb=1- 
3&amp;_nc_sid=09cbfe&amp;_nc_ohc=1EVQdCkudYUAX- 
_oK4D&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fewr1- 
5.fna&amp;oh=db53b58b37272d072239b01f939d602f&amp;oe=60B6C98F" style="width: 
200px; height: 150px; margin-left: -300px;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="businessInfo"> 
<div class="businessName"><a href="">Arielita's Bakery</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="location">Location:Montclair, NJ</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="contactInfo">To order:https://www.arielitasbakery.com/menu 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="connectInfo">Website:https://www.arielitasbakery.com/menu 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show code what you have done so far.

Comment: okI have shared

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question. That is against Stack Overflow's guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this below snippet. Its just an skeleton. It will help you to build such layout.

```css
.product_wrapper {
}

.product_loop {
  display : flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
}
.product_image { background : #ccc; flex : 0 0 20%; height: 150px }
.product_content { flex : 1; padding: 10px }
```

```html
<div class="product_wrapper">
  <div class="product_loop">
     <div class="product_image">
        <img>
     </div>
     <div class="product_content">
        <h3>Product Title</h3>
        <p>Product content goes here</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="product_loop">
     <div class="product_image">
        <img>
     </div>
     <div class="product_content">
        <h3>Product Title</h3>
        <p>Product content goes here</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```